# I cant get Legend to work for my chartjs donut chart

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have tried all the helpfiles on stack, there have been posts where people seem to be manipulating the legend, but i cant get the legend to appear ar all, i dont know what i am doing wrong. 
This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Initso | ChartJS</title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- DONUT CHART -->
    <div class="box box-danger">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Donut Chart</h3>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
          <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
          <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
          <canvas id="pieChart" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"></canvas>
          <div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend"></div>  
      </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->

    <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
    <script src="../../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
    <script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ChartJS 1.0.1 -->
    <script src="../../plugins/chartjs/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="../../dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        /* ChartJS */

        //-------------
        //- PIE CHART -
        //-------------
        // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
        var pieChartCanvas = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");
        var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
        var PieData = [
          {
            value: 700,
            color: "#f56954",
            highlight: "#f56954",
            label: "Chrome",
            labelColor : 'white',
            labelFontSize : '16'
          },
          {
            value: 500,
            color: "#00a65a",
            highlight: "#00a65a",
            label: "IE",
            labelColor : 'white',
            labelFontSize : '16'
          },
          {
            value: 400,
            color: "#f39c12",
            highlight: "#f39c12",
            label: "FireFox",
            labelColor : 'white',
            labelFontSize : '16'
          },
          {
            value: 600,
            color: "#00c0ef",
            highlight: "#00c0ef",
            label: "Safari",
            labelColor : 'white',
            labelFontSize : '16'
          },
          {
            value: 300,
            color: "#3c8dbc",
            highlight: "#3c8dbc",
            label: "Opera",
            labelColor : 'white',
            labelFontSize : '16'
          },
          {
            value: 100,
            color: "#d2d6de",
            highlight: "#d2d6de",
            label: "Navigator",
            labelColor : 'white',
            labelFontSize : '16'
          }
        ];
        var pieOptions = {
          segmentShowStroke: true,
          segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
          segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
          percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts
          animationSteps: 100,
          animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
          animateRotate: true,
          animateScale: false,
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: true,
           legendTemplate : '<ul>'
                  +'<% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++) { %>'
                    +'<li>'
                    +'<span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>\"></span>'
                    +'<% if (datasets[i].label) { %><%= datasets[i].label %><% } %>'
                  +'</li>'
                +'<% } %>'
              +'</ul>'
        };
        //Create pie or douhnut chart
        // You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
        pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
        document.getElementById("js-legend").innerHTML = pieChart.generateLegend();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

2 main issues

1- you are not using the refrence to the actual chart to try and generate the legend `pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);` will create your chart but you want to assign this to a variable so that you can call upon it again to generate the legend like;

```
var myChart = pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
document.getElementById("js-legend").innerHTML =   myChart.generateLegend();
```

2- Your template makes reference to variables not available in the pie chart legend. Instead of `datasets` you want to make reference to `segments`

the full template would look like;

```
 legendTemplate: '<ul>' + '<% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++) { %>' + '<li>' + '<span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span>' + '<% if (segments[i].label) { %><%= segments[i].label %><% } %>' + '</li>' + '<% } %>' + '</ul>'
  };
```

here is an example using the data you provided [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/0ov9k7g2/)

```js
$(function() {
  /* ChartJS */

  //-------------
  //- PIE CHART -
  //-------------
  // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
  var pieChartCanvas = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");
  var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
  var PieData = [{
    value: 700,
    color: "#f56954",
    highlight: "#f56954",
    label: "Chrome",
    labelColor: 'white',
    labelFontSize: '16'
  }, {
    value: 500,
    color: "#00a65a",
    highlight: "#00a65a",
    label: "IE",
    labelColor: 'white',
    labelFontSize: '16'
  }, {
    value: 400,
    color: "#f39c12",
    highlight: "#f39c12",
    label: "FireFox",
    labelColor: 'white',
    labelFontSize: '16'
  }, {
    value: 600,
    color: "#00c0ef",
    highlight: "#00c0ef",
    label: "Safari",
    labelColor: 'white',
    labelFontSize: '16'
  }, {
    value: 300,
    color: "#3c8dbc",
    highlight: "#3c8dbc",
    label: "Opera",
    labelColor: 'white',
    labelFontSize: '16'
  }, {
    value: 100,
    color: "#d2d6de",
    highlight: "#d2d6de",
    label: "Navigator",
    labelColor: 'white',
    labelFontSize: '16'
  }];
  var pieOptions = {
    segmentShowStroke: true,
    segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
    segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
    percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts
    animationSteps: 100,
    animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
    animateRotate: true,
    animateScale: false,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    legendTemplate: '<ul>' + '<% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++) { %>' + '<li>' + '<span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span>' + '<% if (segments[i].label) { %><%= segments[i].label %><% } %>' + '</li>' + '<% } %>' + '</ul>'
  };
  //Create pie or douhnut chart
  // You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
  var myChart = pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
  document.getElementById("js-legend").innerHTML = myChart.generateLegend();
});
```

```css
#js-legend ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#js-legend ul li {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 8px 2px 28px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#js-legend li span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<div class="box box-danger">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h3 class="box-title">Donut Chart</h3>
    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
      <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
    <canvas id="pieChart" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"></canvas>
    <div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.box -->
```

Comment: Dear Quince Thanks for the reply with your variable reference i am getting the legend now, however my legend appears in a list bulleted form. i understand that its because i have not added your css part in my css, however when i did add the js-legend ul etc css in my css file it dint work, I am fairly new to the html css development, And have a difficult time figuring out where to insert the css within the code above to make it work like your fiddle works, i will appreciate your help

Comment: do you have a fiddle of what you have so far so that i can see what you need to add

Comment: or if not a fiddle a screenshot so that I can take a good guess at what is missing

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
session_start();
$FullName = $_SESSION['fullname'];
$DisplayPicture = $_SESSION['displaypicture'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>ChartJS</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  </head>
  <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">

      <header class="main-header">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="../../index.php" class="logo">
          <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
          <span class="logo-mini"><b>IN</b>ae</span>
          <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
          <span class="logo-lg"><b></b></span>
        </a>
        <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
          <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
      <aside class="main-sidebar">
        <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
        <section class="sidebar">
          <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
          <div class="user-panel">
            <div class="pull-left image">
              <img src=<?php echo "../../dist/img/$DisplayPicture"?> class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left info">
              <p><?php echo $_SESSION["fullname"]; ?></p>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- search form -->
          <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </form>
      <!-- /.search form -->
          <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
          <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
            <li><a href="../../index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-pie-chart"></i>
                <span>Charts</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="chartjs.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> ChartJS</a></li>
                <li><a href="morris.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Morris</a></li>
                <li><a href="flot.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Flot</a></li>
                <li><a href="inline.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Inline charts</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>Tables</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="opt/initso/dashboard/pages/tables/simple.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Simple tables</a></li>
                <li><a href="opt/initso/dashboard/pages/tables/data.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Data tables</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="../calendar.php">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <span>Calendar</span>
                <small class="label pull-right bg-red">3</small>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="../mailbox/mailbox.php">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <span>Mailbox</span>
                <small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
        <!-- /.sidebar -->
      </aside>

      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
          <h1>
            ChartJS
            <small>Preview sample</small>
          </h1>
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Charts</a></li>
            <li class="active">ChartJS</li>
          </ol>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <!-- AREA CHART -->
              <!-- DONUT CHART -->
              <div class="box box-danger">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Donut Chart</h3>
                  <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <canvas id="pieChart" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"></canvas>
                    <div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend"></div>  
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
              </div><!-- /.box -->
            </div><!-- /.col (RIGHT) -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->

        </section><!-- /.content -->
      </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
      <footer class="main-footer">
        <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
          <b>Version</b> 2.3.0
        </div>
        <strong>Copyright &copy; 2016 <a href="http://www.initso.com">Initso</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
      </footer>

      <!-- Control Sidebar -->
      <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
        <!-- Create the tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified control-sidebar-tabs">
          <li><a href="#control-sidebar-home-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#control-sidebar-settings-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <!-- Home tab content -->
          <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-home-tab">
            <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Recent Activity</h3>
            <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="javascript::;">
                  <i class="menu-icon fa fa-birthday-cake bg-red"></i>
                  <div class="menu-info">
                    <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Langdon's Birthday</h4>
                    <p>Will be 23 on April 24th</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript::;">
                  <i class="menu-icon fa fa-user bg-yellow"></i>
                  <div class="menu-info">
                    <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Frodo Updated His Profile</h4>
                    <p>New phone +1(800)555-1234</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript::;">
                  <i class="menu-icon fa fa-envelope-o bg-light-blue"></i>
                  <div class="menu-info">
                    <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Nora Joined Mailing List</h4>
                    <p>nora@example.com</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript::;">
                  <i class="menu-icon fa fa-file-code-o bg-green"></i>
                  <div class="menu-info">
                    <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Cron Job 254 Executed</h4>
                    <p>Execution time 5 seconds</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul><!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->

            <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Tasks Progress</h3>
            <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="javascript::;">
                  <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                    Custom Template Design
                    <span class="label label-danger pull-right">70%</span>
                  </h4>
                  <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 70%"></div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript::;">
                  <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                    Update Resume
                    <span class="label label-success pull-right">95%</span>
                  </h4>
                  <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 95%"></div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript::;">
                  <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                    Laravel Integration
                    <span class="label label-warning pull-right">50%</span>
                  </h4>
                  <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width: 50%"></div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript::;">
                  <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                    Back End Framework
                    <span class="label label-primary pull-right">68%</span>
                  </h4>
                  <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" style="width: 68%"></div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul><!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->

          </div><!-- /.tab-pane -->
          <!-- Stats tab content -->
          <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-stats-tab">Stats Tab Content</div><!-- /.tab-pane -->
          <!-- Settings tab content -->
          <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-settings-tab">
            <form method="post">
              <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">General Settings</h3>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                  Report panel usage
                  <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
                </label>
                <p>
                  Some information about this general settings option
                </p>
              </div><!-- /.form-group -->

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                  Allow mail redirect
                  <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
                </label>
                <p>
                  Other sets of options are available
                </p>
              </div><!-- /.form-group -->

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                  Expose author name in posts
                  <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
                </label>
                <p>
                  Allow the user to show his name in blog posts
                </p>
              </div><!-- /.form-group -->

              <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Chat Settings</h3>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                  Show me as online
                  <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
                </label>
              </div><!-- /.form-group -->

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                  Turn off notifications
                  <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right">
                </label>
              </div><!-- /.form-group -->

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                  Delete chat history
                  <a href="javascript::;" class="text-red pull-right"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                </label>
              </div><!-- /.form-group -->
            </form>
          </div><!-- /.tab-pane -->
        </div>
      </aside><!-- /.control-sidebar -->
      <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
           immediately after the control sidebar -->
      <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
    </div><!-- ./wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
    <script src="../../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
    <script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ChartJS 1.0.1 -->
    <script src="../../plugins/chartjs/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="../../plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="../../dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
    <script src="../../dist/js/demo.js"></script>
    <!-- page script -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        /* ChartJS
         * -------
         * Here we will create a few charts using ChartJS
         */
        //-------------
        //- PIE CHART -
        //-------------
        // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
        var pieChartCanvas = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");
        var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
        var PieData = [
          {
            value: 700,
            color: "#f56954",
            highlight: "#f56954",
            label: "Chrome",
            labelColor : 'white',
            labelFontSize : '16'
          },
          {
            value: 500,
            color: "#00a65a",
            highlight: "#00a65a",
            label: "IE",
            labelColor : 'white',
            labelFontSize : '16'
          },
          {
            value: 400,
            color: "#f39c12",
            highlight: "#f39c12",
            label: "FireFox",
            labelColor : 'white',
            labelFontSize : '16'
          },
          {
            value: 600,
            color: "#00c0ef",
            highlight: "#00c0ef",
            label: "Safari",
            labelColor : 'white',
            labelFontSize : '16'
          },
          {
            value: 300,
            color: "#3c8dbc",
            highlight: "#3c8dbc",
            label: "Opera",
            labelColor : 'white',
            labelFontSize : '16'
          },
          {
            value: 100,
            color: "#d2d6de",
            highlight: "#d2d6de",
            label: "Navigator",
            labelColor : 'white',
            labelFontSize : '16'
          }
        ];
        var pieOptions = {
            segmentShowStroke: true,
            segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
            segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
            percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts
            animationSteps: 100,
            animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
            animateRotate: true,
            animateScale: false,
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            legendTemplate: '<ul list-style:none;>' + '<% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++) { %>' + '<li>' + '<span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span>' + '<% if (segments[i].label) { %><%= segments[i].label %><% } %>' + '</li>' + '<% } %>' + '</ul>'};
        //Create pie or douhnut chart
        // You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
        var myChart = pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
        document.getElementById("js-legend").innerHTML = myChart.generateLegend();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```